# Using a truth table to determine if valid or invalid

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have some questions like if $P$ then $Q, P$ therefor $Q$ for example, how can you tell from writing your truth table if therefor $Q$ is valid or invalid? I mean I know its true because Modus Ponens tells me it is but that doesn't really help on more complex issues like;

```
p∨q
r
r → ¬q
−−−−−−
therefore p
```

I can make a table but what am I looking for in it to show me therefore p is valid or invalid.

Thanks

As per conversation with amwhy is this an accurate reflection of what you are trying to explain? I can see that the column with all true R is also true. Therefore its valid![image]

Comment: Thank you both muchly handy :)

Comment: I meant to highlight the P not the R btw, It was just getting late.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check the following:

The argument is valid if and only if whenever you have a row in which (all) entries under the following columns evaluate to true,

$p\lor q$

$r$

$r\rightarrow \lnot q$

Then we must also have $p$ true.

---

This is equivalent to checking whether the statement $$[(p \lor q) \land r\land (r\rightarrow \lnot q)]\rightarrow p$$ is a tautology (i.e., whether the statement evaluates to true for *every* possible truth-value assignment given to $p, q, r$. If it is a tautology, then the argument is valid:

[image]

---

Can you see why the two approaches listed above are equivalent?

Comment: Yer, I think so :) I started working on a table though to see if there was a column in which all entries evaluated to true. and I couldn't see one. I made a column where Q = T R = T and P = T then RvQ would equal true, R would equal True but R --> not Q equales F doesn't it.

Comment: Unless I should be evaluating like ((r -> notQ)->p)

Comment: You look at when each (all) of the *premises* are true (and only when they are all true), to confirm that in those cases, p is also true. You don't need to look at when $p, q, r$ are all true *unless* under that assignment (T, T, T), ALL the premises are true. And under that assignment, you've shown that one of the premises fails. You look at only those truth-value assignments to p, q, r that make all the premises true. In each of those cases, you'll find that $p$ is true.

Comment: OK sorry about the miss-communication. So when we have a row when all of the premises are true, doesn't matter which row in the table? at that stage you look to see if p is also true?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't correct. A row on which the premises and the conclusion are all true only shows that the premises and conclusion could be all true, that is, that they are consistent. This doesn't make the argument valid, as you could have an invalid argument with such a row. What you should check for is the PRESENCE or ABSENCE of a row in which the premises are true while the conclusion is false. As it happens, the argument you asked about is valid, but your truth table is wrong so there such a row.